# Apache Camel 2.15.2 not able to create jetty instance

Tags: jetty, apache-camel

When I was using 2.14 version of camel, I was able to get jetty instance created... however 2.15.2 is giving below error while tomcat loads the app

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jetty' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/camel-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException`

Here is how my camel context config looks like

`bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent"`

Comment: What version of jetty?

Answer (score 0):

Camel hasn't updated their version of Jetty in a very long time.

The official documentation at [camel.apache.org/jetty.html](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) has references to `codehaus.org` (a website that no longer exists!)

The apidoc references at [camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-jetty/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/jetty/JettyHttpComponent.html](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-jetty/apidocs/org/apache/camel/component/jetty/JettyHttpComponent.html) have references to `org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector` which means they are using Jetty 7 or Jetty 8.

[Both Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 are EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).

But all is not lost ...

Starting with [Camel 2.15.0 there is support for Jetty 9](http://camel.apache.org/camel-2150-release.html).

> - Support for Jetty 9 using the new camel-component-jetty9 module

Would recommend upgrading Camel.

Comment: Hi

I would like to upgrade to 2.15.2... however I would like to know the way I can configure it such that I don't get the error specified in my initial question

Answer (score 0):

Since Camel 2.15, Jetty component has been dispatched in two components `camel-jetty8` and `camel-jetty9`. `camel-jetty`, only contains an abstract class that you cannot instantiate.

After importing `camel-jetty8` or `camel-jetty9`, you can simply replace your line:

```
bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent"
```

by

```
bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty8.JettyHttpComponent8"
```

or

```
bean id="jetty" class="org.apache.camel.component.jetty9.JettyHttpComponent9"
```