# Configuring Jetty component in Camel 2.15

Tags: apache-camel, jetty

I'm trying to start using Jetty with Camel.
I have added the dependency to my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

My CamelContext is initialized as follows:

```
public void startCamelContext() throws Exception {
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
    camelContext.addComponent("jetty", new JettyHttpComponent8());
    camelContext.start();
}
```

When I try to start up my service, which has a route with endpoint defined as:

```
jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9000/httpInput
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty8.JettyHttpComponent8.createConnectorJettyInternal(JettyHttpComponent8.java:48)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.createConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:585)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.getSocketConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:527)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.getConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:517)
at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.connect(JettyHttpComponent.java:320)
at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpEndpoint.connect(HttpEndpoint.java:185)
at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpConsumer.doStart(HttpConsumer.java:53)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:2885)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3179)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3115)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3045)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startAllRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:865)
```

The documentation on how to set up the Jetty component is lacking at best. I found a mailing-list entry where it was said that JettyHttpComponent has been made abstract since Camel 2.15 and now that component has to be configured using JettyHttpComponent8 or 9. [link](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/camel-users/201505.mbox/%3CetPan.556a6910.643c9869.1f6@Willems-MacBook-Pro.local%3E)

In my case, I'm using Camel 2.15.5 and the JettyHttpComponent9 isn't available in the classpath, and using 8 gives the exception described above.
I also found related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227336/apache-camel-2-15-2-not-able-to-create-jetty-instance) with no information on how to actually use that component.

Answer (score 0):

That's typically not how the CamelContext is initialized/started.  Please consider using an archetype to get started, then add the Jetty Maven dependency and see if the error can be reproduced.

Camel archetypes can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/camel-maven-archetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

To start a camel context outside spring you need to create a continuous thread to keep camel alive, as explaine here: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Don't worry, I have below some code that will setup a jetty on localhost:8081 for you:

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>


import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;
import org.apache.camel.main.MainListenerSupport;
import org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by mkbrv on 22/06/16.
 */
public class CamelJetty {

        private Main main;

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            CamelJetty example = new CamelJetty();
            example.boot();
        }

        public void boot() throws Exception {
            // create a Main instance
            main = new Main();
            // bind MyBean into the registry
            main.bind("foo", new MyBean());
            // add routes
            main.addRouteBuilder(new MyJettyRouteBuilder());
            // add event listener
            main.addMainListener(new Events());

            // run until you terminate the JVM
            System.out.println("Starting Camel. Use ctrl + c to terminate the JVM.\n");
            main.run();
        }

        private static class MyJettyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("jetty:http://localhost:8081")
                        .process(exchange -> {
                            System.out.println("Invoked timer at " + new Date());
                            exchange.getOut().setBody("Hi, this is Camel!");
                        })
                        .bean("foo");
            }
        }

        public static class MyBean {
            public void callMe() {
                System.out.println("MyBean.callMe method has been called");
            }
        }

        public static class Events extends MainListenerSupport {

            @Override
            public void afterStart(MainSupport main) {
                System.out.println("MainExample with Camel is now started!");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeStop(MainSupport main) {
                System.out.println("MainExample with Camel is now being stopped!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Next just go to http://localhost:8081 and you should see a welcome message. 
Have fun tweaking this further more.